# Azure Data Factory Snowflake ODDBC connection - Cannot create pipeline to run script

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc, azure-data-factory, factory

I'm trying to run a script on Snowflake from Azure Data Factory.
This is so we can use elevated rights to run these script and we can use the scheduling capabilities of ADF to run it on weekly basis. Seems the ODBC connection supports this task better than the native ADF-Snowflake connector.
The idea is to use an ODBC connection from a SHIR VM to run a Snowflake script.
When creating the pipeline, selecting script as the activity, I don't see the ODBC Linked Service I created for this purpose.
The ODBC connection tests OK in ADF and on the SHIR VM. The steps to create this connection are outlined [here](https://medium.com/snowflake/azure-data-factory-connecting-to-snowflake-using-keypair-authentication-906000506345)
Perhaps I need to run a different activity?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out, see steps below:

1. Create a Link Service using the ODBC connector pointing your SHIR VM DSN
2. Create an ODBC that consumes above, you'll need a connection string for above
3. Create an ADF pipeline with a Lookup Activity

   - Use the query function to run your script
   - If more than one command s needed, convert your code to a stored procedure in Snowflake so you can run a single command

Comment: I need to connect adf pipeline to a cloud vm on azure, and execute a shell script, nothing seems to be working for me. any help?